# Closed-form solution for the determinant of a Vandermonde-like matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, closed-form, matrix-decomposition

I'm trying to find a closed-form solution $\forall$ odd integer $n\ge 3$ for the determinant of a matrix with some structure on it. After some manipulation, I've reduced it to the following matrix:

$\small\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{t_{1}^{n}-t_{a}^{n}} & \boldsymbol{t_{2}^{n}-t_{a}^{n}} & \boldsymbol{\cdots} & \boldsymbol{t_{a-1}^{n}-t_{a}^{n}} & nt_{1}^{n-1} & \cdots & nt_{a-1}^{n-1} & nt_{a}^{n-1}\\
\boldsymbol{t_{1}^{n-1}-t_{a}^{n-1}} & \boldsymbol{t_{2}^{n-1}-t_{a}^{n-1}} & \boldsymbol{\cdots} & \boldsymbol{t_{a-1}^{n-1}-t_{a}^{n-1}} & (n-1)t_{1}^{n-2} & \cdots & (n-1)t_{a-1}^{n-2} & (n-1)t_{a}^{n-2}\\
\boldsymbol{\vdots} & \boldsymbol{\vdots} & \boldsymbol{\ddots} & \boldsymbol{\vdots} & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\boldsymbol{t_{1}^{2}-t_{a}^{2}} & \boldsymbol{t_{2}^{2}-t_{a}^{2}} & \boldsymbol{\cdots} & \boldsymbol{t_{a-1}^{2}-t_{a}^{2}} & 2t_{1} & \cdots & 2t_{a-1} & 2t_{a}\\
\boldsymbol{t_{1}-t_{a}} & \boldsymbol{t_{2}-t_{a}} & \boldsymbol{\cdots} & \boldsymbol{t_{a-1}-t_{a}} & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}_{n\times n}$

where $a:=\frac{n+1}{2}$, the **bold** block is $n\times(\frac{n+1}{2}-1)$, and the non-bold block is $n \times \frac{n+1}{2}$.

Although it has some similarities with the [Vandermonde Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) or [some generalizations](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Generalized-Vandermonde-Matrix-Kalman/787fef3971e56df43d95e95f2b98fa67b761bcf7), it's not the same. Using some values of n, its determinant looks pretty simple, which leads me to think that there should be a closed-form solution:

$n=3$:
$$
det\left( 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc} {t_{1}}^3-{t_{2}}^3 & 3\,{t_{1}}^2 & 3\,{t_{2}}^2\\ {t_{1}}^2-{t_{2}}^2 & 2\,t_{1} & 2\,t_{2}\\ t_{1}-t_{2} & 1 & 1 \end{array}\right]
\right)=
-{\left(t_{1}-t_{2}\right)}^4
$$

$n=5$:
$$
det\left( 
    \left[\begin{array}{ccccc} {t_{1}}^5-{t_{3}}^5 & {t_{2}}^5-{t_{3}}^5 & 5\,{t_{1}}^4 & 5\,{t_{2}}^4 & 5\,{t_{3}}^4\\ {t_{1}}^4-{t_{3}}^4 & {t_{2}}^4-{t_{3}}^4 & 4\,{t_{1}}^3 & 4\,{t_{2}}^3 & 4\,{t_{3}}^3\\ {t_{1}}^3-{t_{3}}^3 & {t_{2}}^3-{t_{3}}^3 & 3\,{t_{1}}^2 & 3\,{t_{2}}^2 & 3\,{t_{3}}^2\\ {t_{1}}^2-{t_{3}}^2 & {t_{2}}^2-{t_{3}}^2 & 2\,t_{1} & 2\,t_{2} & 2\,t_{3}\\ t_{1}-t_{3} & t_{2}-t_{3} & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{array}\right]
\right)=
-{\left(t_{1}-t_{2}\right)}^4\,{\left(t_{1}-t_{3}\right)}^4\,{\left(t_{2}-t_{3}\right)}^4
$$

I was wondering if there is a known closed-form solution for this determinant, or if it could be found using the determinant of a generalized Vandermonde matrix

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These seem to be a direct consequence of Schendel's 1891 theorem about "confluent Vandermonde matrices", as explained in (say) ["On a Recursion Formula Related to Confluent Vandermonde",](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.8.766)
Shui-Hung Hou and Edwin Hou, *The American Mathematical Monthly*,
Vol. 122, No. 8 (October 2015), pp. 766-772, or [here](http://www.math.ntua.gr/%7Epapanico/ARTICLES%20NOT%20FOR%20PUBLICATION/vandermonde.pdf) or [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82494391.pdf).  An example of a confluent Vandermonde determinant  is
$$
\begin{vmatrix}x^3&3x^2&y^3&3y^2\\x^2&2x&y^2&2y\\x&1&y&1\\1&0&1&0\end{vmatrix}$$ where certain columns of an ordinary Vandermonde determinant have been replaced by derivatives of others.
Schendel's formula is that this determinant is equal to $(x-y)^4$. If you subtract the third column from the first, and then expand by minors, you end up with the identities
$$
\begin{vmatrix}x^3&3x^2&y^3&3y^2\\x^2&2x&y^2&2y\\x&1&y&1\\1&0&1&0\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}x^3-y^3&3x^2&y^3&3y^2\\x^2-y^2&2x&y^2&2y\\x-y&1&y&1\\0&0&1&0\end{vmatrix}
=
-\begin{vmatrix}x^3-y^3&3x^2&3y^2\\x^2-y^2&2x&2y\\x-y&1&1\end{vmatrix}.
$$
This is the OPs $n=3$ example.

Schendel's general formula for confluent Vandermonde determinants is $\prod_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)^{n_in_j}$, where the value $x_i$ is used to form $n_i$ columns consisting of the first $n_i$ derivatives (the $0$-th up through the $n_i-1$-th derivative) of the usual Vandermonde column $(1,x_i, x_i^2,\ldots)'$.  In the OP's case, all of the $n_i=2$.  The ordinary Vdm formula has all $n_i=1$.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I think this is the answer, I've posted below the example for n=5. Just a minor thing: I think the element (3,2) of the matrix of the last determinant should be 1. But otherwise, this is correct, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it should be a $1$. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

For the case $n=5$, and using the suggestion from the author of the correct answer:

$$
det\left(\begin{bmatrix}t_{1}^{5} & 5t_{1}^{4} & t_{2}^{5} & 5t_{2}^{4} & t_{3}^{5} & 5t_{3}^{4}\\
t_{1}^{4} & 4t_{1}^{3} & t_{2}^{4} & 4t_{2}^{3} & t_{3}^{4} & 4t_{3}^{3}\\
t_{1}^{3} & 3t_{1}^{2} & t_{2}^{3} & 3t_{2}^{2} & t_{3}^{3} & 3t_{3}^{2}\\
t_{1}^{2} & 2t_{1} & t_{2}^{2} & 2t_{2} & t_{3}^{2} & 2t_{3}\\
t_{1} & 1 & t_{2} & 1 & t_{3} & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\right)=\left(t_{1}-t_{2}\right)^{4}\left(t_{1}-t_{3}\right)^{4}\left(t_{2}-t_{3}\right)^{4}=
$$

$$
=det\left(\begin{bmatrix}t_{1}^{5}-t_{3}^{5} & 5t_{1}^{4} & t_{2}^{5}-t_{3}^{5} & 5t_{2}^{4} & t_{3}^{5} & 5t_{3}^{4}\\
t_{1}^{4}-t_{3}^{4} & 4t_{1}^{3} & t_{2}^{4}-t_{3}^{4} & 4t_{2}^{3} & t_{3}^{4} & 4t_{3}^{3}\\
t_{1}^{3}-t_{3}^{3} & 3t_{1}^{2} & t_{2}^{3}-t_{3}^{3} & 3t_{2}^{2} & t_{3}^{3} & 3t_{3}^{2}\\
t_{1}^{2}-t_{3}^{2} & 2t_{1} & t_{2}^{2}-t_{3}^{2} & 2t_{2} & t_{3}^{2} & 2t_{3}\\
t_{1}-t_{3} & 1 & t_{2}-t_{3} & 1 & t_{3} & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\right)=-det\left(\begin{bmatrix}t_{1}^{5}-t_{3}^{5} & 5t_{1}^{4} & t_{2}^{5}-t_{3}^{5} & 5t_{2}^{4} & 5t_{3}^{4}\\
t_{1}^{4}-t_{3}^{4} & 4t_{1}^{3} & t_{2}^{4}-t_{3}^{4} & 4t_{2}^{3} & 4t_{3}^{3}\\
t_{1}^{3}-t_{3}^{3} & 3t_{1}^{2} & t_{2}^{3}-t_{3}^{3} & 3t_{2}^{2} & 3t_{3}^{2}\\
t_{1}^{2}-t_{3}^{2} & 2t_{1} & t_{2}^{2}-t_{3}^{2} & 2t_{2} & 2t_{3}\\
t_{1}-t_{3} & 1 & t_{2}-t_{3} & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\right)=
$$

$$
=-det\left(\begin{bmatrix}t_{1}^{5}-t_{3}^{5} & t_{2}^{5}-t_{3}^{5} & 5t_{1}^{4} & 5t_{2}^{4} & 5t_{3}^{4}\\
t_{1}^{4}-t_{3}^{4} & t_{2}^{4}-t_{3}^{4} & 4t_{1}^{3} & 4t_{2}^{3} & 4t_{3}^{3}\\
t_{1}^{3}-t_{3}^{3} & t_{2}^{3}-t_{3}^{3} & 3t_{1}^{2} & 3t_{2}^{2} & 3t_{3}^{2}\\
t_{1}^{2}-t_{3}^{2} & t_{2}^{2}-t_{3}^{2} & 2t_{1} & 2t_{2} & 2t_{3}\\
t_{1}-t_{3} & t_{2}-t_{3} & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\right)
$$